Telegraf CSV file, returning only one row in prometheus, not returning as timestamp based
I am trying to convert csv data in time series, however only last data populating in Prometheus(both telegraf and prometheus running in same server). Can someone help me, what I am missing.
My telegraf config:
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  debug = false
  quiet = false
# # Read metrics from one or more CSV files
[[inputs.file]]
  ## Files to parse each interval.
  files = ["/usr/temperature.csv"]
  ## File will be read in every interval.
  data_format = "csv"
  csv_header_row_count=1
  ## Specify a time format to use for parsing time from CSV
  csv_timestamp_column = "timestamp"
  csv_timestamp_format = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"

# # Configuration for Prometheus client to expose metrics for scraping

[[outputs.prometheus_client]]
  listen = ":9273"

temperature.csv -
timestamp,temperature,room,device
2024-06-27T12:00:00Z,22.5,room1,device1
2024-05-28T12:05:00Z,22.7,room1,device1
2024-04-22T12:10:00Z,22.8,room1,device1
2024-03-21T12:15:00Z,22.6,room1,device1
2024-02-20T12:20:00Z,22.5,room1,device1
2024-01-23T12:00:00Z,23.0,room2,device2
2024-06-29T12:05:00Z,23.1,room2,device2
below details, I have added for prometheus.yml file -
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'telegraf'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9273']`your text`

expecting time series out put in prometheus

In your csv file, I see only two unique label value pairs -
temparature{room="room1",device='device1'} 22.5
temparature{room="room2",device='device2'} 23.1

You will get only these two entries because Prometheus client picks the latest value of valid unique label value pair. This is expected. If you keep replacing the file contents at regular scrape interval, then only it will become time series data and you will see it in Prometheus as expected.
Also, Prometheus doesn't do backfilling of data since it is real time monitoring. By default I guess it only inserts metrics with +/- 30mins of deviation from current timestamp.
Hope this helps!
